# Formatting time to MM:SS even if its not a complete minute

Tags: javascript, formatting, momentjs

I'm trying to format time hh:mm:ss (music/podcast duration) using moment.js and .format():

```
[...]
let tkd = moment.duration(trackLenght);
let prg = moment.duration(trackProgress);
let fin = prg.format("hh:mm:ss") + ' / ' + tkd.format("hh:mm:ss");
```

This code works as expected ex: `02:40 / 05:55`.

But when any are below 1 minute, the mm:ss formatting becomes `32 / 05:55`.

Is there any way of forcing it to `00:32 / 05:55` without manipulating the string? (Using .format() works, but if the trackLenght is below 0 seconds the resulting string is `360 miliseconds / 05:55`). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) of moment-duration-format I find that there is a second parameter to pass for some more configuration in `.format()`.

try with that code

```
let fin = `${prg.format('HH:mm:ss', { trim: false })} / ${tkd.format('HH:mm:ss', { trim: false })}`;
```

and the correct string for get the hours is with `HH`.